# MySQL query for date range

Tags: mysql, time, period

I need a SQL query for retrieving data which is included in selected time period, time period is string which user selects from calendar.

For example, if user selects time period **'2012-07-01'** to **'2012-07-04'** and I have the following **table**:

```
ID ||  start_date  ||  end_date
 1 ||  2012-07-02  || 2012-07-04
 2 ||  2012-07-06  || 2012-08-05
 3 ||  2012-07-01  || 2012-09-01
 4 ||  2012-06-25  || 2012-09-01
```

If a write a sql **query** like this:

```
SELECT ID, start_date, end_date
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  start_date BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-04'
```

This **returns** all rows which started from '2012-07-01' to '2012-07-04'

```
ID ||  start_date  ||  end_date
 1 ||  2012-07-02  || 2012-07-04
 3 ||  2012-07-01  || 2012-09-01
```

But, I **want** all data which is included in this period, so result must be:

```
ID ||  start_date  ||  end_date
 1 ||  2012-07-02  || 2012-07-04
 3 ||  2012-07-01  || 2012-09-01
 4 ||  2012-06-25  || 2012-09-01
```

Row with ID 4 also I want to be in result, because user selected time period is under start_date and end_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, start_date, end_date
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  start_date BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-04'
```

You are only selecting by start date, you may ask by:

```
(start_date between begin, end) OR
(end_date   between begin, end) OR
(start_date <= begin AND end_date >= end)
```

so:

`(start_date between begin, end )`: you have all events that starts in the range

`(end_date between begin, end)`: you have all events that finish in the range

`(start_date <= begin AND end_date >= end)`: you have all events that are active in the range

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT ID, start_date, end_date 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE start_date <= '2012-07-01' AND
      end_date >= '2012-07-04';
```

Comment: I tried this, but last row is not included in result because end_date is '2012-09-01' and this is not between '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-04', and also start_date is  not between '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-04' (it is '2012-06-25')

Answer (score 1):

You must to cover three types of events:

1. Starting in this interval
2. Ending   in this interval
3. Starting before and ending after the interval.

So you should use this:

```
SELECT ID, start_date, end_date
FROM   your_table
WHERE  (start_date  BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-04')
   OR  (end_date    BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-04')
   OR  (start_date <= '2012-07-01' AND
        end_date   >= '2012-07-04')
```

Quick overview:

```
Interval:                S---------E
Case 1  :      ---|      :         :            NOT WANTED
Case 2  :      ----------:----|    :            WANTED
Case 3  :      ----------:---------:------      WANTED - YOUR PROBLEM
Case 4  :         |------:----|    :            WANTED
Case 5  :         |------:---------:------      WANTED
Case 6  :                :  |---|  :            WANTED
Case 7  :                :  |------:------      WANTED
Case 8  :                :         :  |---      NOT WANTED
```

Your problematic case is the case 3. It will be covered by adding extra condition `start_date <= '2012-07-01' AND end_date >= '2012-07-04'`.

Comment: I tried this, but last row is not included in result because end_date is '2012-09-01' and this is not between '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-04', and also start_date is  not between '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-04' (it is '2012-06-25')

Comment: Fixed. Please give me feedback.