# Getting 3 days data from mysql date field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date_time field in mysql in the following format:

```
date_time
-----------------
Wed Nov 08 2012 16:22:06 GMT 0
```

How do i get the three days data from the current date.

Comment: This question has been asked dozens of times. Did you research?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query for date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795049/mysql-query-for-date-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet that the column `Date_Time`'s data type is varchar, and if that's the case, you should convert it to valid date using `STR_TO_DATE`, example,

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%i:%s')
FROM tableName
WHERE   DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%i:%s')) >=
        DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/797bd/8)

SOURCES

- [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)
- [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [DATE *formats*](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)
- [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)
- [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this query, foe example

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_time,"%d-%m-%y") FROM your_tablename;
```

Comment: this just formats the date, this is not his solution

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_time>=DATE_SUB('2012-09-27',INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

OR

```
SELECT created_date FROM property WHERE created_date>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```